# How do I write from Spark to multiple partitions?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a small file that's just about 1.5 KB and being written to S3 as just 1 file. I'd like to actually write it to S3 as multiple part files to test partitioning, but I'm having trouble.
How do I set it up to do so? Is there anything I should be doing differently than here?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType, BooleanType, ArrayType, IntegerType, TimestampType

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.ui.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", "4") \
    .config("spark.files.maxPartitionBytes", "500") \
    .master("yarn-client") \
    .getOrCreate()

myschema = StructType([\
                         StructField("field1", TimestampType(), True), \
                         StructField("field2", TimestampType(), True), \
                         StructField("field3", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("field4", StringType(), True), \
                         StructField("field5", StringType(), True)
                         ])

mydf= spark.read.load("s3a://bucket/myfile.csv",\
                     format="csv", \
                     sep=",", \
                     # inferSchema="true", \
                     timestampFormat="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                     header="true",
                     schema=scheduled_schema
                    )

mydf.coalesce(5) 

df_scheduled.write.csv(path="s3a://bucket/output",\
                     header="true",
                    )
```

Comment: Replace `mydf.coalesce(5)` with `mydf.repartition(5)`.

Comment: Still not working with `repartition`

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working? what do you see on s3?

Comment: I'm seeing the same output as before, which is a folder with a `_SUCCESS` file and one output file

Comment: did you get the anwser?